# how to parse a string into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to parse a string to separate the lists within the string. I currently have the string:

```
string = "[['q1', '0', 'q1'], ['q1', '1', 'q2'], ['q2', '0', 'q2'], ['q2', '1', 'q1']]"
```

Is there any way to parse string so that the dictionary key is the first element of the list and the value of the key is the next to elements. For example:

```
{'q1': ('0','q1'), 'q1': ('1','q2'), 'q2': ('0','q2'), 'q2': ('1', 'q1')}
```

Comment: you can't have duplicate elements in dictionary as keys. q1 and q2 are repeated twice in your expected output, you can't have this.

Comment: unless you change the behaviour of a Python dictionnary by redefining a class but I guess that's not the purpose :)

Comment: is there a way to add another value to an existing key in a dictionary?

Comment: yes, you could have like:`{'q1': [('0','q1'), ('1','q2')], 'q2': [('0','q2'), ('1', 'q1')]}`. is this you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insted of `dictionary` you can have list: 
you can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse python data structure from string

```
>>> import ast
>>> my_string = "[['q1', '0', 'q1'], ['q1', '1', 'q2'], ['q2', '0', 'q2'], ['q2', '1', 'q1']]"
>>> k = ast.literal_eval(my_string)
>>> k
[['q1', '0', 'q1'], ['q1', '1', 'q2'], ['q2', '0', 'q2'], ['q2', '1', 'q1']]
>>> [[x[0],tuple(x[1:])] for x in k]
[['q1', ('0', 'q1')], ['q1', ('1', 'q2')], ['q2', ('0', 'q2')], ['q2', ('1', 'q1')]]
```

Comment: this worked and my problem as been fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSON but the **string format has to be a dict** and you **cannot have 2 times the same key**:

```
import json

string ='{"q": ["0", "q1"], "q1": ["1", "q2"], "q3": ["1", "q1"], "q2": ["0", "q2"]}'

dict = json.loads(string)

print dict
Output: {'q': ['0', 'q1'], 'q1': ['1', 'q2'], 'q3': ['1', 'q1'], 'q2': ['0', 'q2']}
```

Comment: A list of lists is a valid JSON, the issue is OP's string contains single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

To keep the duplicates and conform the input format:

```
import collections
import json
string = "[['q1', '0', 'q1'], ['q1', '1', 'q2'], ['q2', '0', 'q2'], ['q2', '1', 'q1']]"
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for (k, v1, v2) in json.loads(string.replace("'",'"')):
    d[k].append((v1, v2))
```

With `eval` (if you trust your input):

```
import collections
string = "[['q1', '0', 'q1'], ['q1', '1', 'q2'], ['q2', '0', 'q2'], ['q2', '1', 'q1']]"
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for (k, v1, v2) in eval(string):
    d[k].append((v1, v2))
```

Contents of d:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    'q1': [('0', 'q1'), ('1', 'q2')],
    'q2': [('0', 'q2'), ('1', 'q1')]
})
```

EDIT: and with no library at all.

```
string = "[['q1', '0', 'q1'], ['q1', '1', 'q2'], ['q2', '0', 'q2'], ['q2', '1', 'q1']]"
d = {}
for (k, v1, v2) in eval(string):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append((v1, v2))
```

I'm unable to make it a one-liner though :-)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(string)
[['q1', '0', 'q1'], ['q1', '1', 'q2'], ['q2', '0', 'q2'], ['q2', '1', 'q1']]
>>> list=ast.literal_eval(string)
>>> d={}
>>> for l in list:
...     d[l[0]]=tuple(l[1:])
>>> d
{'q1': ('1', 'q2'), 'q2': ('1', 'q1')}
```

key is always unique in dict thats why in result showing updated key value pair

Comment: This is not what OP asked for

Comment: @Hackaholic yes i kno just giving idea

Comment: I didnt downvote . but as i said OP dosent want this

Answer (score 2):

You could get nested dictionaries from your string (a little less straightforward than the previous answers). Thanks to Alex Martelli for his answer to [Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth)

```
import ast

def update(d, u):
    for k, v in u.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            r = update(d.get(k, {}), v)
            d[k] = r
        else:
            d[k] = u[k]
    return d

def listToDict(l):
    temp = l[-1]
    for value in l[-2::-1]:
        temp = {value: temp}
    return temp

input = "[['q1', '0', 'q1'], ['q1', '1', 'q2'], ['q2', '0', 'q2'], ['q2', '1', 'q1']]"

res = {}
for l in ast.literal_eval(input):
    update(res ,listToDict(l))
print res
```

Output:

```
{'q1': {'1': 'q2', '0': 'q1'}, 'q2': {'1': 'q1', '0': 'q2'}}
```