# Merging dictionaries in Python - doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I'm looking for a way to merge dictionaries by other means than `dict(a.items()+b.items())` is doing.

Example:

```
foo = {'cart':
  {'item':
    {'1':
      {'amount':
        'X',
      },
    },
  },
}

bar = {'cart': 
  {'item':
    {'2': 
      {'amount': 
        'Y',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Wanted result:

```
res = {'cart':
  {'item':
    {'1':
      {'amount':
        'X'
      },
    },
    {'2': 
      {'amount': 
        'Y',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Actual result (gotten bei dict(foo.items() + bar.items()):

```
res = {'cart':
  {'item':
    {'2': 
      {'amount': 
        'Y',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what you have tried already ?

Comment: ...so you want to update the dictionary under `res['cart']`, and not `res` itself. Or do you have any other key besides `cart` you want to update?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dictionaries of dictionaries merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/dictionaries-of-dictionaries-merge)

Comment: Best answer I've seen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3233356/893113

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth)

Answer (score 1):

Found that code snippet which does fairly well for my usecase:

```
def deepupdate(original, update):
    """
    Recursively update a dict.
    Subdict's won't be overwritten but also updated.
    """
    for key, value in original.iteritems():
        if not key in update:
            update[key] = value
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            deepupdate(value, update[key])
    return update
```

Comment: Do note that this mutates the second dictionary, which might not be what you want.