# Merge two dictionaries and persist the values of first dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
first = {"phone": {
                "home": "(234) 442-4424"
            },
         "address":"xyz" 
            }


second = {"phone": {
                "home": "(234) 442-4424",
                "home1": "(234) 442-4424"
            },
         "address":{} 
            }
```

I want merge two dictionaries first over second, meaning the first dictionary doesn't lose its previous values and only the missing key values are added into first.

The final dictionary should look like this:

```
final = {"phone": {
                "home": "(234) 442-4424",
                "home1": "(234) 442-4424"
            },
         "address":"xyz" 
            }
```

Also what if when we use list of dictionaries like : -

```
    first = {"phone": {
                "home": "(234) 442-4424"
            },
         "address":[{"home":""},{"office":""}]
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Update()` will work, simply copy the second dict and apply the first one. So the value of the first will replace the second and not the reverse way.

```
first = {"phone": {"home": "(234) 442-4424"},"address":"xyz"}
second = {"phone": {"home": "(234) 442-5555","home1": "(234) 442-4424"},"address":{}}

# recursive deep update you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3233356/956660
import collections

def update(d, u):
    for k, v in u.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
            r = update(d.get(k, {}), v)
            d[k] = r
        else:
            d[k] = u[k]
    return d

third = second.copy()
update(third, first)

print(third)
```

> {'phone': {'home': '(234) 442-4424', 'home1': '(234) 442-4424'}, 'address': 'xyz'}

Comment: great it is working as required. Let me understand the logic which u have used.

Comment: Hi cyrbil, It is working fine but fail when we take list of dictionaries in it. I am beginners in python so unable to figure out how to fix this. I have updated the ticket.

Comment: Hi, please post another question for that. Addressing one issue at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Do `second.update(first)`. Any keys in both will have their value set to the value in `first` and any keys that are in `first` but not `second` will be added to `second`.

Comment: yes I have used this but I dont want change first key value.

Comment: @user3048148: If you don't want to change either dictionary, then do `third = second.copy()` and then `third.update(first)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just add the missing key/value pairs into the first dictionary, you can just add them to the first instead of creating a new dictionary.

```
first = {}
second = {}

for key in second.keys():
  if key not in first:
    first[key] = second[key]
```

---

Edit: your comment "it wont work with multilevel dictionary"

Actually, it will..technically speaking.

```
first = {"Person1" : {"Age": "26", "Name": "Person1", "Phone number": "XXXXXX"}}
second = {"Person1": {"Interests": "fishing"}, "Person2": {"Age": "26", "Name": "Person2", "Phone number": "XXXXXX"}}
```

In this case, the `first`dict will get the `Person2`object, but will not change the `Person1` object, as it is already there!

Comment: but it wont work with multi level dictionary

Comment: @user3048148 you didn't specified whether your dict is multilevel or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your *dictionnaries* have following structure:

- each element is a dictionnary
- values are either plain strings or dictionnaries

Assuming that the requirement is:

- if a key exist only in one of the 2 elements to merge, keep its value
- if a key exists in both elements:

  - if the value in first element is a plain string, keep its value
  - if the value in first element is a dict and the value in second is a string, keep value from first
  - if the values in both elements are dict merge them with priority to first

A possible code is then:

```
for k, v in first.iteritems():
    if isinstance(v, str):
        final[k] = v
    elif k in final:
        if isinstance(final[k], dict):
            final[k].update(first[k])
        else:
            final[k] = first[k]
    else:
        final[k] = first[k]
```