# Merge two dictionaries with list of element and persist the values of first dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
first = {"phone": {
            "home": "(234) 442-4424"
        },
     "address":[{"home":""},{"office":""}]
        }


second = {"phone": {
            "home": "(234) 442-4424",
            "home1": "(234) 442-4424"
        },
     "address":[]
        }
```

I want merge two dictionaries first over second, meaning the first dictionary doesn't lose its previous values and only the missing key values are added into first.

The final dictionary should look like this:-

```
final = {"phone": {
            "home": "(234) 442-4424",
            "home1": "(234) 442-4424"
        },
     "address":[{"home":""},{"office":""}]
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried already? What have you tried, and what didn't work?

Comment: plz check this link it is working fine for dictioanry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912772/merge-two-dictionaries-and-persist-the-values-of-first-dictionaries but dont give desired result when dictionary have list of items

Comment: The last answer I gave you merge recursively **dictionnaries**, to merge dict that contain arrays, you need to check object type (dict or array) and merge accordingly and recursively. Please show some research and try, this post is a series of 3 other posts where you ask without even trying.

Comment: Old questions were [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33916875/956660) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33912772/956660).

Comment: If you dont have answer then leave it.

Comment: You have asked to create new question so I have  did. Unfortunately you dont have answer.

Comment: I have checked the object type list but unable to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using following method:
My actual data was :

```
first_json = {"basic_info":[{"indexPos": "0", "isUpper": "1", "placeHolder": "NAME THIS CARD (Required)", "value": "ddd", "keyName": "CardName"},{"indexPos": "0", "isUpper": "1", "placeHolder": "NAME THIS CARD (Required)sddd", "value": "", "keyName": "CardName11"}]}

second_json = {"basic_info": [{"indexPos": "0", "isUpper": "1", "placeHolder": "NAME THIS CARD (Required)sddd", "value": "wwwwwwwwww", "keyName": "CardName"},{"indexPos": "0", "isUpper": "1", "placeHolder": "NAME THIS CARD (Required)sddd", "value": "dsfsdfd", "keyName": "CardName11"}]}

third_json = second_json.copy()

self.mergeDict(third_json, first_json)
print third_json
```

and our mergeDict function :

```
     def mergeDict(self,s, f):
      for k, v in f.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
            r = self.mergeDict(s.get(k, {}), v)
            s[k] = r
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            result = []
            """ TODO : optimization """

            if k == 'basic_info':
               for  valf in v:
                    if 'keyName' in valf:
                        for vals in s.get(k, {}):
                                if valf['keyName'] in vals.values() and vals['value'] !="" and valf['value'] == "":
                                    valf['value'] = vals['value']
                        result.append(valf)
               """ Reverse loop is for check  extra data in second business card """          
               for vals1 in s.get(k, {}):
                       if 'keyName' in vals1:
                          check = 0  
                          for valf1 in v:
                              if vals1['keyName'] in valf1.values():
                                 check = 1
                          if not check:
                              result.append(vals1)                            
            else:
               v.extend(s.get(k, {})) 
               for myDict in v:
                    if myDict not in result:
                        result.append(myDict)

            s[k] = result    
        else:
            #------------- If the key is blank in first business card then second business card value assign to it -----#
            if not v and s.get(k, {}):
                #f[k] = s.get(k, {})
                pass
            else:    
                s[k] = f[k]
    return s
```

This merge function gives us what was required. Please suggest if I could optimize further.

Answer (score -1):

You could use first.extend(second). But maybe you have to iterate over the children of the first dictionary and extend every child separately.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question, it's a comment, at best.