# Change value in dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to change values I have stored in a dictionary of dictionaries.

This is the code I tried to implement. The problem is p remains the same, and I'm not sure how to update p.

```
j = {'a':1.0}
k = {'c':3.0}
p = {'e':j,'f':k}
for n in p.itervalues():
    print n
    n = {key:value/3.0 for key, value in n.items()}
    print n

print p
```

Comment: You're creating a new dictionary and assigning it the identifier `n`. That has **nothing** to do with the dictionary referenced by `p`.

Comment: Do you know how I can implement this correctly?

Comment: If you're trying to *change* the dictionary, you need something like `n[key] = new_value`.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign the updated value back to the original dictionary.

```
j = {'a':1.0}
k = {'c':3.0}
p = {'e':j,'f':k}
for k,v in p.items():
    p[k] = {key:value/3.0 for key, value in v.items()}

print p
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `n = {...}`, you are assigning a different dictionary to n.

If you want to change both `p` and the original dictionaries (`j` and `k`), you could do something like this:

Since dictionaries are mutable, you can replace it's content with that of another dict like this:

```
def replace_dict(original, new):
    original.clear()
    original.update(new)
```

And then do `replace_dict(n, {key:value/3.0 for key, value in v.items()})`.

---

Since all you are doing is applying a function ("divide by 3") to each value, you can also do something like this:

```
    for key, value in n.iteritems():
        n[key] = value / 3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth mentioning you are using python2.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
j = {'a': 1.0}
k = {'c': 3.0}
p = {'e': j, 'f': k}
for v in p.itervalues():
    print "v before inplace updates:", v
    for k, v_inside in v.items():
        print "v[k] before inplace change", v[k]
        v[k] = {key: value / 3.0 for key, value in v.items()}
        print "v[k] after inplace change", v[k]
print "p after inplace edits:\n", p
```

Produces this output:

```
v before inplace updates: {'a': 1.0}
v[k] before inplace change 1.0
v[k] after inplace change {'a': 0.3333333333333333}
v before inplace updates: {'c': 3.0}
v[k] before inplace change 3.0
v[k] after inplace change {'c': 1.0}
p after inplace edits:
{'e': {'a': {'a': 0.3333333333333333}}, 'f': {'c': {'c': 1.0}}}
```

Comment: I now see, always someone is faster :-D still post this, just because others can immediately see the produced output