# Update values from a "default dictionary" without removing its keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries, the first is what the default values of the second one should fall back to if they are not present or not defined, and it is somewhat like this:

```
default_dict = {
    'lorem': {
        'foo': 'white',
        'bar': 'black',
    },
    'ipsum': {
        'xyz': '',
        'abc': {},
        'qwe': {}

    }
}
```

And the second looks like this:

```
custom_dict = {
    'lorem': {
        'bar': 'blue',
    },
    'ipsum': {
        'xyz': 'apple',
        'qwe': { 'one': 'strawberry' }

    }
}
```

**Is there any way I can "update" from the `default_dict` with the values from the `custom_dict`?**

**The desired result would look something like this:**

```
custom_dict = {
    'lorem': {
        'foo': 'white',
        'bar': 'blue',
    },
    'ipsum': {
        'xyz': 'apple',
        'abc': {},
        'qwe': { 'one': 'strawberry' }

    }
}
```

I've tried doing `default_dict.update(custom_dict)` and then `custom_dict = default_dict`, but as you can imagine I'm just getting `custom_dict` back untouched... So the keys of `default_dict` are getting removed when it is updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3233356/367273

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
d={a:b for k,v in custom_dict.items() for a,b in v.items()}
print({k:{a:d.get(a,b) for a,b in v.items()} for k,v in default_dict.items()})
```

A dictionary comprehension + a nested dictionary comprehension would work.

Output:

```
{'lorem': {'foo': 'white', 'bar': 'blue'}, 'ipsum': {'xyz': 'apple', 'abc': {}, 'qwe': {'one': 'strawberry'}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the structure of your dictionaries are always like above so the following code works fine:

```
for item in default_dict:
    for value in default_dict[item].keys():
        if value not in custom_dict[item].keys():
            custom_dict[item].update({value: default_dict[item][value]})
```

good luck