# Rearrange keys in a dict to be under a given key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict with a key `slug` and I want to put all key/value pairs in the dict into a child dict with the name taken from the `slug`.

For example, given this input:

```py
{
    "tasks": {},
    "task_defaults": {
        "retry": {
            "count": 3,
            "delay": 2
        }
    },
    "slug": "test"
}
```

I want this output:

```py
{
    "test": {
        "tasks": {},
        "task_defaults": {
            "retry": {
                "count": 3,
                "delay": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth

Comment: `'tasks'` key has an empty dictionary as its value in the input dictionary but in output dictionary, it's not the case. Is that a mistake or expected?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Do not delete your question when you get your answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions.

Comment: ok, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK with returning a new `dict` object that references the inner values from the input dictionary, you can do this:

```
def group_by_slug(data):
    return {
        data['slug']: {
            key: value for key, value in data.items()
            if key != 'slug'
        }
    }
```