# Generalized csv to json conversion

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I've been having to do a lot of this lately (pretend it's a csv, tabular is just easier read). Converting csv files to json with varying schemas.

I'd never call myself a "python programmer" but I work a lot with data and it's my language of choice for wrangling.

I'd like some help generalizing this, I think it'd be a good learning exercise so "code-for-me" isn't required. Just some nudges in the right direction. If you read all this ... thanks.

What is an appropriate structure for the metadata input?
Just any tips/thoughts

Sample input, expected result, current state, and quarter baked goal state.

```
Toplvl TopLvlAttr1 TopLvlAttr2 SecondLvl SecondLvlAttr1 ThirdLvl ThirdLLvlAttr1
T1     TA1_1       TA2_1       S1        SA1_1          TR1      TRA_1
T1     TA1_1       TA2_1       S1        SA1_1          TR2      TRA_2
T1     TA1_1       TA2_1       S1        SA1_1          TR3      TRA_3
T1     TA1_1       TA2_1       S2        SA1_2          TR4      TRA_1
T1     TA1_1       TA2_1       S2        SA1_2          TR5      TRA_2
T1     TA1_1       TA2_1       S2        SA1_2          TR6      TRA_3
T2     TA2_1       TA2_2       S3        SA1_3          TR7      TRA_1
T2     TA2_1       TA2_2       S3        SA1_3          TR8      TRA_2
T2     TA2_1       TA2_2       S3        SA1_3          TR9      TRA_3
```

The expected json looks like

```
{
  "T1": {
    "TopLevelAttribute1": "TA1_1",
    "TopLevelAttribute2": "TA1_2",
    "SecondLevels": {
      "S1": {
        "SecondLevelAttribute1": "SA1_1",
        "ThirdLevels": {
          "TR1": {
            "ThirdLevelAttribute1": "TRA_1"
          },
          "TR2": {
            "ThirdLevelAttribute1": "TRA_2"
          },
          "TR3": {
            "ThirdLevelAttribute1": "TRA_3"
          }
        }
      },
      "S2": {
        "SecondLevelAttribute1": "SA2_1",
        "ThirdLevels": {
          "TR4": {
            "ThirdLevelAttribute1": "TRA_5"
          },
          "TR5": {
            "ThirdLevelAttribute1": "TRA_5"
          },
          "TR6": {
            "ThirdLevelAttribute1": "TRA_6"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "T2": {
    "TopLevelAttribute1": "TA2_1",
    "TopLevelAttribute2": "TA2_2",
    "SecondLevels": {
      "S3": {
        "SecondLevelAttribute1": "SA1_3",
        "ThirdLevels": {
          "TR7": {
            "ThirdLevelAttribute1": "TRA_7"
          },
          "TR8": {
            "ThirdLevelAttribute1": "TRA_8"
          },
          "TR9": {
            "ThirdLevelAttribute1": "TRA_9"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The pattern that I just generally plug&chug with looks like

```
import json

with open('sample_csv_input.csv','r') as sd:
    data_lines = sd.readlines()
    sample_output = {}
    for line in data_lines:
        data_attributes = line.split(',')
        toplvl, toplvl_attr1, toplvl_attr2, secondlvl, secondlvl_attr1, thirdlvl, thirdlvl_attr1 = data_attributes
        third_level_element = {
            thirdlvl: {
                "ThirdLevelAttribute1": thirdlvl_attr1
            }
        }
        if toplvl in sample_output.keys():
            if secondlvl in sample_output[toplvl]["SecondLevels"].keys():
                sample_output[toplvl]["SecondLevels"][secondlvl]["ThirdLevels"].update(third_level_element)
            else:
                sample_output[toplvl]["SecondLevels"][secondlvl] = {
                    "SecondLevelAttribute1": secondlvl_attr1,
                    "ThirdLevels": third_level_element}

        else:
            sample_output[toplvl] = {
                "TopLevelAttribute1": toplvl_attr1,
                "TopLevelAttribute2": toplvl_attr2,
                "SecondLevels":{
                    secondlvl:{
                        "SecondLevelAttribute1": secondlvl_attr1,
                        "ThirdLevels": third_level_element
                    }
                }
            }

with open('sample_json.output.json','w') as so:
    json.dump(sample_output, so, indent=4)
```

I know this is bad.

I'm trying to do something more generalized, like have a piece of metadata that defines the structure and a generic function that takes it from there. But getting stuck.

```
  # Hierarchy Attribute Map
  {
    "TopLvl":{
        "Attributes":[{"TopLevelAttribute1": "TopLvlAttr1","TopLevelAttribute2": "TopLvlAttr2"}],
        "Children": [{"SecondLevels": "SecondLvl"}]
    },
    "SecondLvl":{
        "Attributes":[{"SecondLevelAttribute1": "SecondLvlAttr1"}],
        "Children": [{"ThirdLevels": "ThirdLvl"}]
    },
    "ThirdLvl"{
        "Attributes":[{"SecondLevelAttribute1": "ThirdLLvlAttr1"}]
    }
  }


import csv
import json

class csv2json:
    def __init__(self, input_csv_file, hierarchy_map):
        self.input_csv_file = input_csv_file
        self.labeled_rows = self.read_with_labels()
        self.converted_json = self.convert2json()
    def get_children(self):
        pass
    def get_attributes(self):
        pass
    def insert_element(self):
        pass
    def read_with_labels(self, input_csv_file):
        csv_rows = []
        with open(input_csv_file, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            field = reader.fieldnames
            for row in reader:
                csv_rows.extend([{field[i]: row[field[i]] for i in range(len(field))}])
        return csv_rows
    def convert2json(self):
        pass
```

Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: Whatever works well for you works. It's often counterproductive to look for generic ways to wrangle data, because data comes in all shapes and sizes. I've always found it easier to write separate code to process differently arranged data and store the code with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jinja2` package and setup templates to generate your data, something like this:

```
{
   "{{ toplvl }}": {
      "TopLevelAttribute1": "{{ toplvl_attr1 }}"
   ...
}
```

Run the template through each row and merge the generated json via something like this - [Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth)