# Javascript - Update value in nested dictionary regardless of depth

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Hi first of all I would like to state that yes, this question has been answered here [Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth) however, this is in `Python`.

I would like to know if there's a `Javascript` approach to solving this issue.

Let's say I have a dictionary as such:

```
{
  "group1" : {
    "name" : "NAME1"
  },
  "group2" : {
    "name" : "NAME2"
  }
}
```

How would I be able to replace `"NAME1"` with lets say `"Bob White"` without doing this `dict["group1"]["name"] = "Bob White"`?

Could someone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each property and set the value of its `name` property:

```js
const obj = {
  "group1" : {
    "name" : "NAME1"
  },
  "group2" : {
    "name" : "NAME2"
  }
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => obj[e].name = "Bob White")

console.log(obj)
```