# Editing value in dict with nested dict while being able to still update without nested

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

### The problem

I have a few JSON Files which are built different and I need a code to be able to edit a value as well in the dicts which are just one dict and others who have nested dicts without removing other values.

### Examples

So I got for example one JSON File which is like this:

`JSON/id_list.json`

```json
{"whatever": [ID_1, ID_2, ID_3]}
```

`JSON/main_id.json`

```json
{"value": "yes"}
```

or another on like this

`JSON/id_data.json`

```json
{"data": {"ID_1": {"type1": 0, "type2": 1}, "ID_2": {"type1": 0, "type2": 0}}}
```

### Current Code

My current code is only able to edit the first and / or second so I wanted it to be general but just didn't seem to find an answer

`Functions/get_json.py`

```py
def get(name: str, path: str, load: bool):
    if load:
        _load(path)
    return loadedf[name]

def update(name: str, text, path: str, load: bool):
    if load:
        _load(path)
    loadedf[name].remove(get(name, path, False))
    loadedf[name].append(text)

    with open(path, "w+"):
        json.dump(loadedf, nfl)

def _load(path: str):
    preloadf = open(path, 'r')
    global loadedf
    loadedf = json.load(preloadf)
```

`game.py`

```py
from Functions import get_json.py
async def random_function():
    get_json.get('whatever', '/JSON/id_list.json', True)
    get_json.update('value', 'no', '/JSON/main_id.json', True)
```

### New Code Idea

`game_new.py`

```py
from Functions import get_json.py
async def random_function():
    get_json.get(['whatever'], '/JSON/id_list.json', True)
    get_json.get(['data', 'ID_1', 'type2'], '/JSON/id_data.json', True)
    get_json.update(['data', 'ID_2', 'type1'], '/JSON/id_data.json', False)
```

But I have no Idea how to do or realize this.

### What I tried so far

I tried `dict.update()`, doing it with for loops like

```py
prev = loadedf
for i in name:
    prev = prev[i]

    prev.remove(get(name, path, False)[0])
```

or with some weird stuff like `__setattr()__` and with a way with which I wasn't happy as it can't handle JSONs generally and was really long and complicated;

I tried to do it with the optional parameters `deep`, `name2` and `name3` and do it with an `if elif` to do `if deep == 2: return loadedf[name][name2]`.

---

The code used here might be outdated from what I had or partly not working as I wrote it completely new because I rewrote it a few times to reach my goal; to be generally able to do all this with JSON Files.

Comment: If the scope of the problem you're facing limited to updating the dictionary returned by `json.load`, perhaps this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth).

Comment: tested it in a few cases and "prereleased" it for my discord bot and the result was that now stuff is happening which I couldn't even explain and I still can't update one value without removing the other values from the dict

Comment: Generally you should use JSON solely as an I/O format. You should transform the objects into instances of user-defined classes otherwise (if you have a schema this can be done easily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an Idea yesterday evening and built it in to get this working code

```py
def edit_json(name: list, text, path: str, load: bool, execute: str):
    try:
        if load:
            _load(path)

        prev = "loadedf"
        for entry in name:
            if isinstance(entry, int):
                prev += f"[{entry}]"
            else:
                prev += f"[\"{entry}\"]"

        if execute == "add" or execute == "append":
            exec(prev + ".append(text)")
        elif execute == "remove":
            exec(prev + ".remove(text)")
        elif execute == "update":
            exec(prev + " = text")

        with open(path, "w+") as nfl:
            json.dump(loadedf, nfl)
```

So this is now my solution also with the idea of having `name` as an array built in