# Python: update a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I am given a nested dicionary `my_dict` and another nested dict `update`: a sequence of keys (valid in `my_dict`) with a value to be assigned to the leaf at this sequence. For example,

```
my_dict = {
    'city': 'NYC',
    'person1': {'age': 25, 'name': 'Anna'},
    'person2': {'age': 30, 'name': 'Bob'}
}

update0 = {'city': 'London'}
update1 = {'person1': {'age': 24}}
update2 = {'person2': {'age': 31}}
```

I need a function `UpdateDict` such that `UpdateDict(my_dict, update1)` will return

```
{
    'city': 'NYC',
    'person1': {'age': 24, 'name': 'Anna'},
    'person2': {'age': 30, 'name': 'Bob'}
}
```

and `UpdateDict(my_dict, update0)` will return

```
{
    'city': 'London',
    'person1': {'age': 25, 'name': 'Anna'},
    'person2': {'age': 30, 'name': 'Bob'}
}
```

In c++ I would have used explicit pointers/references to subdicts, but in python I'm not sure what to do, given that I don't know in advance the depth of the second argument (`update` one).

**EDIT:** if I try `{**my_dict, **update1}` or `my_dict.update(update1)` I get

```
{
    'city': 'NYC',
    'person1': {'age': 24},
    'person2': {'age': 30, 'name': 'Bob'}
}
```

which is not desired: it does not change the value at a particular leaf only, but instead removes all the keys at the same level.

**EDIT2:** if someone needs this, I've solved it as follows

```
def UpdateDict(original, param):
    for key in param.keys():
        if type(param[key]) == dict:
            UpdateDict(original[key], param[key])
        else:
            original[key] = param[key]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why `my_dict.update(update)` wouldn't work.

Comment: @mkrieger1: because it removes other keys at that level

Comment: I see. Then you probably need a recursive solution.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I probably do, but I don't see how to avoid changing the value on a copy of a subdict, and instead change it in the original dict. I also don't get why this question was immediately closed, even though the suggested link does not answer it

Comment: Unless you explicitly create a copy, you should normally operate on references already.

Comment: @mkrieger1 indeed, that worked

Comment: @Barmar the duplicate should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth

Comment: @mkrieger1 that's better, thanks

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yeah, that question is directly on point, although there are some answers to my duplicate that show how to do it recursively.